# In ColdFusion 8, is there a way to see the SQL inside a failing cfquery?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfquery

I have a `<cfquery>` which generates some SQL inside. It's failing, but I have no idea why. I tried wrapping it inside a `<cftry> <cfcatch>` block, and dumping the result. However, result is undefined. Is there another way to see what the SQL looks like?

Comment: How about providing your query.

Comment: I think the easiest way to accomplish this is simply turning debugging on for your IP address. Failing that, you can specify a result attribute in your `<cfquery>` tag and dump that variable in your `<cfcatch>` block - http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_p-q_17.html

Answer (score 10):

Inside your `<cfcatch>`, do this:

```
<cfdump var="#cfcatch#"><cfabort>
```

This should show you the query that it tried to run.

Comment: Trick: For those running CF9+, you can also do `<cfdump var="#cfcatch#" abort>`, which is a tad shorter.

Answer (score 2):

If it fails and the error isn't showing SQL, then it may be an issue with the cfqueryparam, maybe a datatype mis-match, can you provide the text of the error? Maybe even the SQL code?

Answer (score 0):

Replace every < with &lt; and then cfabort

Answer (score -1):

Remove your cfquery and replace with cfoutput.  You can remove the cfqueryparam and just output the values.  You should produce a SQL statement that will run fine in a query analyzer.